# Why controller asking full path to go to view in mvc3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I wrote one partialview for action method.if giving the full path of that partial view in action method it's going but directly return view() it's not returning view.why it's asking full path of the view?
please let me know.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchResults(FormCollection collection)
        {
 return View("/Areas/Admin/Views/Search/ShowResults.ascx",vm); --it's working
//return View(); --it's not returning view.why?
}
```

route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                                 // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                              // URL with parameters
                new { area = "", controller = "home", action = "index", id = "" },   // Parameter defaults
                new string[] { "MVC.Web.Controllers" }
            );
```

Comment: As that view is not assigned to action SearchResults framework cannot find respective view. Right click action name and click go to view what does that shows?

Comment: while right clicking on that action going to that view but running of that code not going to partial view.

Comment: by using javascript anonymous method i am calling that action when loading the page.

Comment: can u show your route, whats is vm there,

Comment: here vm is list<application> data passing to view.

Comment: then why havent u passed it to second one, and r u using razor or aspx.Please post ur error as well

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is failing is that you do not have a view called `SearchResults` (the name of your action method). The view you are returning is `ShowResults`.  Since you are using a view that is not named the same as the actual action name, you need to specify it.  In addition, since you are returning a partial view, its a good practice to tell MVC that you are doing so using the `return PartialView` method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResults(FormCollection collection)
{
  return PartialView("ShowResults", vm);
}
```

This will work as long as the `ShowResults` view is located in a view directory with the same name as the controller or located in a Shared view folder.  If the view is not located in one of these locations, then you will need to specify the full path to the view as the view engine will not be able to locate it on its own.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResults(FormCollection collection)
{
    return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Search/ShowResults.ascx",vm);
}
```

Also, when using full paths, be sure to preface with the `~` character as this tells IIS/.NET to start looking at the root of your application, not the root of the site.  It may work now, but if you move your site to a virtual directory or something not at the root of the hosted domain, it will fail.